# Regular Expression Partial Match returning default argument if not found

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create a regular expression, to parse a SIP Contact information.

The goal is to get 3 groups from a string; The username, the ipaddress and another parameter which is optional...

My issue occurs when the 3rd group is not found...  The regex returns nothing... not event the first two groups...

**The question is**

Is there a way to tell the system that a group is optional, that can be anywhere, and if the group is not there to return a specific value?

**Current Pattern**

`.*<sip:(.*)@(.*):[1-9]\d*?.*(?=MyArg1=(true|false))`

**Inputs**

After the first ";" all parameters are separated with ";" but the "name=value" can also be only a value.  i.e ;value1=true;tag1;tag2;value2=false

```
"Display" <sip:CD001@172.24.0.52:5060;MyArg1=true;fs_path=sip%3A172.24.0.23%3Br2%3Don%3Blr>
"Display" <sip:CD001@172.24.0.52:5060;fs_path=sip%3A172.24.0.23%3Br2%3Don%3Blr;MyArg1=true>
"Display" <sip:CD001@172.24.0.52:5060;fs_path=sip%3A172.24.0.23%3Br2%3Don%3Blr;MyArg1=false>
"Display" <sip:CD001@172.24.0.52:5060;fs_path=sip%3A172.24.0.23%3Br2%3Don%3Blr;allo=true;MyArg1=false>
"Display" <sip:CD001@172.24.0.52:5060;fs_path=sip%3A172.24.0.23%3Br2%3Don%3Blr;MyArg1=false;MyArg2=true>
"Display" <sip:CD001@172.24.0.52:5060;fs_path=sip%3A172.24.0.23%3Br2%3Don%3Blr;MyArg1=true;MyArg2=true>
"Display" <sip:CD001@172.24.0.52:5060;fs_path=sip%3A172.24.0.23%3Br2%3Don%3Blr>
```

At the same time, I'm pretty sure that the pattern can be more efficiant...

Thank you for your time!
Sebastien

Comment: "if the group is not there to return a specific value" : not with just a regular expression. What tool are you using ?

Comment: I'm using Freeswitch, wich is a c++ API.

Comment: @SébastienDemers you are welcomed. Feel free to upvote/accept.

Answer (score 0):

How about an alternation? I think this is an appropriate way to solve this.

```
(?|.*<sip:(.*)@(.*):[1-9]\d*?.*?(?=MyArg1=(true|false))|.*<sip:(.*)@(.*):[1-9]\d*?.*)
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/8rgt4y/1/)

If you do not need the beginning of the string, use this slightly optimized pattern:

```
(?|<sip:(.*)@(.*):[1-9]\d*?.*(?=MyArg1=(true|false))|<sip:(.*)@(.*):[1-9]\d*?.*$)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!